# How to convert jdbc results to immutable collection

Tags: scala, immutability, spray-json

I have a small application written in scala that sends a request to mysql, receives the result, then convert it to json and sends to some http server. I use java jdbc and mysql connector to connect to a database and spray-json for scala collection to json conversion. So, I create a connection to db, execute a query and then get a result with `getResultSet()`. Then I iterate through it, and copy result to a mutable map:

```
while(result.next()) {
    val SomeExtractor(one, two) = result
    map.update(one, map.getOrElse(one, List()) ::: List(two))
}
```

This works fine, but then I have to convert the result to immutable map, cause spray-json can't convert mutable collections to json, AFAIK. Is there a good way to convert the jdbc result here to an immutable collection without coping it to temporary mutable map? Maybe it is possible to do using streams somehow? I'm asking cause it looks like there must be some cool functional pattern to do it, that I have no idea about.

p.s. By the way, I can't just use Slick, cause it doesn't support stored procedures, AFAIK.

Comment: May I point you to a JDBC Scala interface that does allow you to use `toList` on returns from queries and supports stored procedures? https://github.com/novus/novus-jdbc (I wrote it while I worked there.)

Comment: @wheaties Thanks, can I get this library from maven repo using sbt?

Comment: You know, that might help if I made it available for download but I got right up to that point and never published it outside of the company Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can't do significantly better than what you've got. Under the hood of Scala's functional cleverness is code that looks a lot like yours. Also, don't forget that mutable `Map`s have a `toMap` method that returns an immutable `Map`.

**Long Answer**: You're looking to make JDBC code interface with Scala code. JDBC's API is not designed for use from functional languages, so you'll definitely need some mutable/imperative code to help bridge the gap. It's really just a question of the path of least resistance.

If you were simply building a one-to-one map, you'd be well served by a `MapBuilder`. Scala includes `Builder` classes for most of its data structures, which use temporary, private, mutable structures to build an immutable structure as efficiently as possible. The code would look something like:

```
val builder = Map.newBuilder[Int, Int]
while(result.next()) {
  val SomeExtractor(one, two) = result
  builder += one -> two
}
return builder.result
```

*However*, you're really building a MultiMap - a map from keys to multiple values. Scala does have a `MultiMap` trait in its standard library, but it's not ideal for your use case. It's mutable, and stores values in mutable `Set`s rather than `List`s, so we'll ignore it for now.

Scala's standard library does have a `groupBy` method on its `Traversable` trait, which does more-or-less what you're looking for. We've got a `ResultSet` rather than a `Traversable`, but in principle we could write some glue code to wrap the `ResultSet` in a `Traversable`, and take advantage of this existing code. Something like the following:

```
// strm has side effects, caused by rs.next - only ever call it once, and re-use result if needed.
def strm: Stream[(Int, Int)] = if (rs.next) SomeExtractor.unapply(rs).get #:: strm else Stream.empty
return strm.groupBy(_._1)
```

This will work, but we've got a scary warning about side effects, and we haven't actually gained any performance. If you look at the source code for `Traversable.groupBy` [(see code on GitHub)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.3/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L325), it's actually doing much the same thing you are - building a mutable `Map` with our data, and then converting it to an immutable `Map` at the end.

I think the approach you've already got is close to optimal - just return `map.toMap`.

Oh, and I've assumed that SomeExtractor extracts a pair of `Int`s.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! But isn't it possible to use a stream here somehow? Than call its `takeWhile(result.next())` method to extract all results to stream? And then use it as a collection. Though I don't know if it is supported in spray-json.

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like this. I think it's quite safe to do it this way, as long as it is accessed from single thread, cause the result would be copied to the stream, that is immutable. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you want a Stream, you'll need glue code. @Aleksey's `getStreamOfResults` is probably the best way to do this. Once you've got this, you can call `groupBy` on the `Stream`. But under the covers, it will still create a mutable map.

Comment: Apologies, I deleted the comment you're replying to. The code you're referring to was `def strm: Stream[(Int, Int)] = if (rs.next) SomeExtractor.unapply(rs).get #:: strm else Stream.empty`, which is equivalent to  @Aleksey's code, but slightly golfier (the implementation of `Iterator.toStream` uses the same trick of calling itself recursively). As long as you ensure the code's used from the same thread, the stream doesn't outlive the JDBC session, and you never attempt to re-use the `ResultSet` (such as by calling `strm` multiple times. It should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/) will do just what you want.

Alternatively, here is the code I once wrote. It gives you a Stream of JSON docs and meta info and it's based on Lift JSON library, but you can easily change it to other JSON implementations. It works quite well.

```
case class ColumnMeta(index: Int, label: String, datatype: String)

def runQuery(dbConnection: Connection, query: String): (List[ColumnMeta], Stream[JObject]) = {
    val rs = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query).executeQuery
    implicit val cols = getColumnMeta(rs.getMetaData)
    (cols, getStreamOfResults(rs))
  }

  /**
   * Returns a list of columns for specified ResultSet which describes column properties we are interested in.
   */
  def getColumnMeta(rsMeta: ResultSetMetaData): List[ColumnMeta] =
    (for {
      idx <- (1 to rsMeta.getColumnCount)
      colName = rsMeta.getColumnLabel(idx).toLowerCase
      colType = rsMeta.getColumnClassName(idx)
    } yield ColumnMeta(idx, colName, colType)).toList

  /**
   * Creates a stream of results on top of a ResultSet.
   */
  def getStreamOfResults(rs: ResultSet)(implicit cols: List[ColumnMeta]): Stream[JObject] =
    new Iterator[JObject] {
      def hasNext = rs.next
      def next() = rowToObj(rs)
    }.toStream

  /**
   * Given a row from a ResultSet produces a JSON document.
   */
  def rowToObj(rs: ResultSet)(implicit cols: List[ColumnMeta]): JObject = {
    val fields = for {
      ColumnMeta(index, label, datatype) <- cols
      clazz = Class.forName(datatype)
      value = columnValueGetter(datatype, index, rs)
    } yield (label -> value)
    JObject(fields map { case (n, v) => JField(n, v) })
  }

  /**
   * Takes a fully qualified Java type as String and returns one of the subtypes of JValue by fetching a value
   * from result set and converting it to proper type.
   * It supports only the most common types and everything else that does not match this conversion is converted
   * to String automatically. If you see that you results should contain more specific type instead of String
   * add conversion cases to {{{resultsetGetters}}} map.
   */
  def columnValueGetter(datatype: String, columnIdx: Int, rs: ResultSet): JValue = {
    val obj = rs.getObject(columnIdx)
    if (obj == null)
      JNull
    else {
      val converter = resultsetGetters getOrElse (datatype, (obj: Object) => JString(obj.toString))
      converter(obj)
    }
  }

  val resultsetGetters: Map[String, Object => JValue] = Map(
    "java.lang.Integer" -> ((obj: Object) => JInt(obj.asInstanceOf[Int])),
    "java.lang.Long" -> ((obj: Object) => JInt(obj.asInstanceOf[Long])),
    "java.lang.Double" -> ((obj: Object) => JDouble(obj.asInstanceOf[Double])),
    "java.lang.Float" -> ((obj: Object) => JDouble(obj.asInstanceOf[Float])),
    "java.lang.Boolean" -> ((obj: Object) => JBool(obj.asInstanceOf[Boolean])),
    "java.sql.Clob" -> ((obj: Object) => {
      val clob = obj.asInstanceOf[Clob]
      JString(clob.getSubString(1, clob.length.toInt))
    }),
    "java.lang.String" -> ((obj: Object) => JString(obj.asInstanceOf[String])))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not use Slick, cause it doesn't support stored procedures. Thanks for your answer and for a stream example!